# What's wrong with my algorithm that's giving me incorrect duplicate removal values?

Tags: java, string, algorithm, for-loop, char

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a string but I'm not sure why my algorithm's wrong.  It's giving me an output of `baa` instead of `bans` which's the correct output.

During my attempt to debug, I tried switching the `i` to `j` inside `sb.deleteCharAt();` but that gave me a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5`  error.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
public static void removeDuplicate(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Duplicates have been, the resulting string is => " + sb);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "bananas";
    removeDuplicate(s);
}
```

Comment: Lots of algorithms doing what you need here : https://www.baeldung.com/java-remove-repeated-char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, deleting elements from a collection while loop through it is a bad idea, because it can cause wrong logic base on index changes.
Just put some special case like "baaana", your solution will fail easily because when you trying to found "a" at index 2, you remove it and skip comparing with the "actual" index 3 because its index is decreased to 2 after removing. 
And another thing you should know. In Java, String is immutable, that means when you change a string, you actually assign the variable with the new one. So those function should return a new String instead of modifying input.

With this type of problem, i suggest you should use a hash data type to memorize the distinct elements, so you can solve this with an O(n) time complexity.

```
public static String removeDuplicate(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Set<Character> metChars = new HashSet<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(!metChars.contains(c)) {
            sb.append(c);
            metChars.add(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are wrong. You should make the comparison with string builder in your loops, not with string itself, as it changes. Second, you're using wrong index in removal. Here's the correct program:

```
public static void removeDuplicate(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);

    for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < sb.length(); j++) {
            if(sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(j)) {
                sb.deleteCharAt(j);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Duplicates have been, the resulting string is => " + sb);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "bananas";
    removeDuplicate(s);
}
```

The output is:

> Duplicates have been, the resulting string is => bans

Answer (score 1):

You can use [distinct()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) :

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
yourstr.chars().distinct().forEach(c -> sb.append((char) c));
```

Best

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you remove a character in your `StringBuilder`, you effectively change the indexes of all further characters.

In your example `bananas`, if you remove the second a (pos 3 since we start at 0), you get the string `bannas`. Then, when you want to remove the 3rd a of `bananas`, at pos 5, you end up removing the s.